# Чи є слово самий?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Чи є в українській мові  слово «самий» (самий кращий, самий гарний)? Адже дане слово надзвичайно часто вживають на телебаченні та на письмі і воно надзвичайно "ріже слух".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Коротко:** слово існує, але не для ступенювання прикметників

---

Українська мова цілком має такого слова, з прикметниками теж ладить:

[Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 9, 1978. — Стор. 26.](http://sum.in.ua/s/samyj)

> **4.** Уживається в поєднанні з прикметниками:
>
> **a)** з відносними для підкреслення найвищого ступеня вияву ознаки. 
>   *Як крикне [цар] На самих пузатих — Всі пузаті до одного В землю провалились!* (Тарас Шевченко, I, 1963, 251); *— В котрому вікні він сидів? — знов спитав Микола, — В самому крайньому* (Нечуй-Левицький, II, 1956, 201); *Цей час [70-ті роки XIX ст.] в Галичині був самим мертвим, як свідчать історики* (Михайло Коцюбинський, III, 1956, 29); *На самому сонячному місці пастовня яснів блідим золотом островок* (Леся Українка, III, 1952, 651); *— Між моїм родом — батьками, дідами, самими далекими пращурами — я перший іду до культури, до світла* (Степан Васильченко, IV, 1960, 14); *Дівчинка тихенько засміялася, затупала ніжками по щаблях драбини і з самого останнього сміливо зіскочила на сіно* (Михайло Стельмах, II, 1962, 77);
>
> **б)** (*розмовне, рідко*) з якісними звичайного і вищого ступеня — для творення форм найвищого ступеня, з якісними найвищого ступеня — для їх підсилення.
>
> — *Ти саму велику біду мені робиш, ти губиш мене* (Квітка-Основ'яненко, II, 1956, 339); *Було піде [пан] з Сенькою-кухарем у загони, намітить самого ситого вола, та й звелить убити* (Олекса Стороженко, I, 1957, 195); *— Подай нагайку, — Батьку, ну для чого вам ця нагайка? — А для того, сучий ти сину, щоб не показував на картах трьох доріг, а одну, та саму кращу* (Олександр Довженко, I, 1958, 199); *— Он у Дейкалівці самого найкращого жеребця в артілі вкрали* (Григорій Тютюнник, Вир, 1964, 15).

Але:

- Більшість прикладів **«художнього» напряму**, цебто не завше чи не для всіх може бути прикладом; також за [четвертим] останнім порядком вказує на «неважливість»;
- Цей словник робився за совітські часи: сам по собі сумнівний через омосковчення, наприклад старший словник Грінченка такого пояснення чи прикладу не включає, а инші [перші за порядком]:

[Словарь української мови / Упор. з дод. влас. матеріалу Б. Грінченко : в 4-х т. — К. : Вид-во Академії наук Української РСР, 1958. 
Том 4, ст. 98.](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/53241-samyj.html)

> **Самий**, **-а**, **-е.**, *мѣст.* Самый.
>
> *Ой топи мене, моя мати, да на самеє денце*. Чуб. V. 569. *В собаках сама сила.* Рудч. Ск. І. 121. *Докатав до самого краю*. Ном. *Ой дай коню овса по самиї перса*. Чуб.

[Словарь української мови / Упор. з дод. влас. матеріалу Б. Грінченко : в 4-х т. — К. : Вид-во Академії наук Української РСР, 1958. 
Том 4, ст. 98.](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/53242-samyj-2.html)

> **Самий** 2, **сама** и **самая**, **саме** и **самеє**, *мѣст*. Одинъ, только одинъ, лишь.
>
> *Самий борщ та борщ без нічого що-дня як їсти, то хиба наїсися? Уже то не даром тобі так солодко самій сидіти дома!* Рудч. Ск. I. 132. *У самій сорочці вискакує з хати на мороз. І постіль убога — самая солома.* Чуб. III. 382. *Оставили саме бадилля.* Рудч. Ск. І. 52.
>
> **самі за себе**. Одни только. *А багато було людей в церкві? — Людей, мамо, не було нікогісінько, тільки самі за себе москалі.* Ном. № 828.
>
> *Ум.* **саменький**, **самесенький**.

І **головне «але»**: чинний — 2015 року — правопис стверджує такий зразок:

[§ 69. Ступенювання прикметників](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par69)

> **Вищий ступінь прикметників**
>
> **1.** Вищий ступінь прикметників утворюється додаванням:
>
> **а)** суфікса **-іш-** або **-ш-** до основи чи до кореня звичайної форми якісного прикметника: *нов**-іш-**ий, повн**-іш-**ий, син**-іш-**ий, дешев**-ш-**ий, солод**-ш-**ий;* /101/
>
> **б)** слів **більш**, **менш** до звичайної форми якісного прикметника: *більш вдалий, більш глибокий, менш вередливий*.
>
> **Найвищий ступінь прикметників**
>
> **2.** Найвищий ступінь прикметників утворюється додаванням:
>
> **а)** префікса **най-** до форми вищого ступеня: *найбільший, найкраща, найменше;*
>
> **б)** слів **найбільш**, **найменш** до звичайної форми якісного прикметника: *найбільш зручний, найбільш стійка, найменш приємне.*
>
> Для посилення вживаються при формах найвищого ступеня прикметників частки **що** і **як**; пишуться вони з прикметниками разом: *щонайсильніший, якнайбільший, якнайшвидший.*

Comment: Можливо варто якось винести на початок повідомлення висновок, бо не всі й дочитають до кінця;)